# domain certification, webservers, load-balancer and licensing

Tags: certificates, web-browser, public-key-infrastructure, certificate-authority, digital-signature

I have just a single domain.
I have 1 reverse proxy (l7 load balancers) and 3 webservers serving www.example.com

I am getting an ssl pro certificate for the domain and I want to understand the number of licenses I will need.

Let's assume that self-sign cert is out of the equation for the entire path between `client <-> lb <-> webservers`

choice 1) cert on loadbalancer only,  communication between loadbalancer <--> backend webserver is pure http.

choice 2) cert on loadbalancer, cert on webservers

client <-> lb <- webserver>  all https

=============================

For choice2, can I just use 1 cert and install the same cert+ptvkey+intermediacert on the loadbalancer and all the webservers?

Is the number of licenses required for a domain a pure commercial restriction or are there really some technical parameters in the cert itself that restrict the no of servers that can use it?

Comment: What kind of licenses you are talking about? Do you mean certificates? There is no technical restriction for using the same certificate on multiple systems.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich yeap, I am talking about ssl certificates for usage on websites. Saw from Symantec website, it is 1 cert per server.

Comment: I have no idea what this license should be for and I cannot find anything about this on a quick search at a Symantec site (they offer lots of products). Please add a clear reference to what kind of license you refer to, i.e. link to the description on the product page of the vendor, cite the part of the product page etc. Apart from that again, there are no **technical** limitations on how many systems a certificate can be used.

Comment: Questions about a vendors licensing requirements are questions for the vendor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can I just use 1 cert and install the same cert+ptvkey+intermediacert on the loadbalancer and all the webservers ?

Yes, you can use single purchased certificate on all affected components (load balancers, proxy, web servers) as long as they serve the same domain name. You don't need to purchase separate certificate (with the same name) for each component.

Comment: I am seeing -> "Unlimited server licenses" feature in 1 of the ssl sites.  why is this even a "feature" if a cert can be installed in all affected components of the same domain name ?

Comment: and now in Symantec live chat -> the sales rep said " only physical servers (actual servers) would need to have the certificate installed on it. If you have additional physical server, then there will be additional server licence required for Symantec certificates"

Comment: Sales are sales. From my understanding, by license they mean an unique key pair for specified domain. Like if you would use separate certificate and key pair for each component. I wouldn't bother with this, just export your cert to PFX and copy it to all target servers that will serve specified domain name.

Comment: Technically one license is necessary. A company issuing certificates may, however, demand more money. In practise, they will be able to check this but may never do so.